# Read php tags inside a non-php file and execute

Tags: php, templates, tags

What I'm trying to achieve is build a simple and lightweight theme engine, where anyone will be able to create his own template easily, I have managed to do this using PHP, and for example, if someone wants to input the logo, all they have to do is use: {logo} , and etc.

The template files extensions are '.inc'.. My problem is, i don't know how to allow users to still execute php code, using PHP (< ?php ?>) tags.

I have tried both adding this in my htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .inc
```

I know other template engines exist, such as smarty, but id rather go for something a lot more simpler.

Comment: Solution to problem: Use Twig :)

Comment: @alex . I dont really get what you mean?.
@NikiC , I really preffer if i could do this on my own template engine, so i know how it all works and i like to keep things very simple.
As for Twig, does it allow both php tags and {} tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too many people will be happy to use a template engine which requires adding new web server handlers to use it.

Therefore it would be advisable to use a standard fully supported extension like **.php** instead of **.inc** or in case you are really willing to use **.inc** simply include the file with output buffering turned on and collect the output in a variable like this:

```
ob_start();
require "template.inc";
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

`$content` will hold whatever was inside `template.inc` so you can do whatever you want with it.

Not only that but if your `template.inc` file contains PHP variables they will be parsed too.

Comment: I tried using the standard .php extension but that didnt work. including the file with output buffering worked seamlessly, thank you very very much. I have been scratching my head on this for some time now !

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with htaccess rules. You need to evaluate PHP content right after you finished interpreting your template tags. For instance:

```
eval( "?> $content_of_template <?php " );
```

Comment: ... taking great care to sanitize $content_of_template, of course.

Comment: @Scott Yeah, it is desirable, but template engines are not always secure. There are many template engines that uses pure PHP only.

Comment: If you go with this, be sure to strip out MANY of PHP's functions, as a good amount of them could be used maliciously.  You might even be better off approving/disapproving all PHP templates before they are allowed onto the site.

Comment: @Jaxo I wont be approving or disproving any php templates, because I will be selling this script as a part of a much bigger script, so anyone that wants to create his own template, its his own problem. :)